# How to clean cloudways Varnish cache after cleaning statics on magento 2 side

Tags: magento2, event-observer, cache, plugin, varnish

I wrote a class that works if I call it through pure php. It looks something like this

```
class CloudwaysAPIClient
{
    const API_URL = "https://api.cloudways.com/api/v1";
    ...
    public function purgeCache()
    {
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

After that I call it with the necessary parameters

```
$apiClient = new CloudwaysAPIClient('...', '...');
$apiClient->purgeCache();
```

How can I call my class after cleaning static files through a button in the admin panel
System > Cache Management > Flush Static Files Cache

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the event

> clean_static_files_cache_after

which gets dispatched after static files are cleaned.

Create an observer and from there you can call your class.

Comment: can I have a small example? sorry i'm not very good at magento

Comment: You can go through this guide on how to create an observer. https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/extension-dev-guide/events-and-observers.html

Comment: you need to add this observer in your module.

Comment: Thanks, it works, do not tell me the event for cleaning fpc?

Comment: Welcome :) You cannot specifically target fpc. but you can observer event 'adminhtml_cache_refresh_type'. this event gets fired on all three action- when you specifically flush any type cache, flush all or flush system cache. For fpc you can check in your observer if there is a 'types' param in post request and it contains value 'full_page' or if controller action is any of the two 'flush all or flush system'.